# Can't delete Integer from ArrayList

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to create an Android App which uses Android Room as it's Database. I have linked two tables via their ids. If i check, whether the parent should be destroyed (because there is no child left), I come across an error with an ArrayList, that contains those child ids. I can't remove the id integer from the ArrayList of the parent.

IdList.contains(childId) returns false.
Logging all integers in the IdList shows that the childId *is* in the IdList.

IdList.indexOf(childId) returns the right value.
trying IdList.removeAt(IdList.indexOf(childId)) throws an Error tho: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

IdList.remove(childId) does nothing at all (childId can't be found).

```
entryModel.entry.value?.let { meal ->
    val parentDao = db.mealParentDao()

    val parent = parentDao.findById(meal.childParentId)
    parent?.let {
        if (parent.childrenIds != null &&parent.childrenIds!!.size > 1) {

            var location: Int? = null
            parent.childrenIds?.forEachIndexed { index, i ->
                if (i == meal.childId) location = index
            }

            if (location != null) parent.childrenIds?.removeAt(location!!)

            parent.parentType?.remove(meal.childType)
            parentDao.updateMealSpecies(parent)
        } else parentDao.deleteById(parent.speciesId)
    }
    db.mealChildDao().deleteById(meal.childId)
}
```

I'd expect the ArrayList without the id of the deleted child, but the ArrayList either stays the same or brings my App to a Crash.

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: does moving parent.childrenIds?.removeAt(location) into the forEachIndexed() help? your current code is only sets the location for a single index, hence only one childrenId is removed

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what's going on here, but there's a well known problem with `ArrayList.remove()` when dealing with integers.

The `remove()` method is overloaded.  It can either be called with an object to remove that object, or an integer index to remove the element at that index.  When `remove()` is passed an integer, even if that integer happens to be an element of the list, it presumes it to be an index.

Is it possible that that's the issue?

Comment: I don't think so. Kotlin has to functions remove() and removeAt(). Remove() uses an element, removeAt() an index. But i'll try to convert the list to long and see what will happen.